# Open the start menu using Powershell

Tags: windows-7, powershell, start-menu

Am currently working on a business process automation software and literally user actions are simulated by robots. I need to pass some information to the start menu of my windows 7 and i was wondering if the windows start menu could be opened using a powershell script? As the information to open a powershell can be understood by the robots. Please any suggestions would be nice.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible using a **little VB**.

Copy this code into Notepad, and save as `startmenu.vbs`. [Make sure it **doesn't** get saved as startmenu.vbs.txt]

```
set wShell=wscript.createobject("wscript.shell")
wShell.sendkeys "^{ESC}"
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Then, you can just run it with `cscript C:\somefilepath\startmenu.vbs`.

(Obviously, you'll have to specify the path where you save it to)

---

Or, translated to a **Powershell** solution:

```
$wShell = New-Object -ComObject "wscript.shell"
$wShell.SendKeys("^{ESC}")
```

Which can be further shortened to:

```
(New-Object -ComObject "wscript.shell").SendKeys("^{ESC}")
```

Comment: Translated to powershell: `$wShell = New-Object -ComObject "wscript.shell";
$wShell.SendKeys("^{ESC}")`

Comment: or shortened as `(New-Object -ComObject "wscript.shell").SendKeys("^{ESC}")`

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers You should put that in as an answer (with a brief explanation of what it's doing). :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly more verbose solution that doesn't emulate key presses (for cases where CTRL+ESC is bound to another program/command etc).

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Win32API
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]    
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, String lpWindowName);    
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]    
    private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);  

    public static void OpenStartMenu ()
    {
        const int SC_TASKLIST = 0xf130;
        const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x112;
        IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", "");
        SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_TASKLIST, 0);
    }
}
"@
[Win32API]::OpenStartMenu()
```