# Create shortcut to Windows 10 Start

Tags: windows, windows-10, shortcuts, links, file-shortcut

How can I create file shortcut (.lnk) to Windows 10 Start?

I mean the shortcut which opens that popup window which appears after click to START button on a keyboard.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of what you mean exactly by editing your question

Comment: Do you mean like `shell:common start menu` ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The start menu can only be opened using a keyboard, faking keyboard events or by clicking the start menu button.

Answer (score -2):

You can open it using a power shell script then link to that, this should point you in the right direction [Open the start menu using Powershell](https://superuser.com/questions/1072516/open-the-start-menu-using-powershell)